# How do I calculate the value of this limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How do I calculate the limit of the following sequence?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\dotsm
\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2}\right)
$$

A given hint is that the inequality
$$x - \frac{x^2}{2} < \log(1+x) < x$$
holds for any positive number $x$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. From the *given* hint one may write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^4}<\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}
$$ then one may use the known closed forms
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk, \quad \sum_{k=1}^nk^2.
$$

Comment: Or note $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^4}\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}.$